# pandas: inserting one blank row and one row with index by group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure how to insert a blank row and a row with index after each group. 
I was able how to insert a blank row (thanks to the references on SO), however, am having trouble figuring out how to insert another row with index.

original:

```
+------+---------+-------+--+
|  id  | country | score |  |
+------+---------+-------+--+
| 1011 | JPN     |     5 |  |
| 1011 | JPN     |     5 |  |
| 1011 | NZ      |     4 |  |
| 1011 | NZ      |     5 |  |
| 1012 | NZ      |     5 |  |
| 1012 | AUS     |     6 |  |
| 1012 | NZ      |     6 |  |
| 1013 | AUS     |     5 |  |
| 1013 | AUS     |     5 |  |
+------+---------+-------+--+
```

Insert one blank row

```
+------+---------+-------+
|  id  | country | score |
+------+---------+-------+
| 1011 | JPN     |     5 |
| 1011 | JPN     |     5 |
| 1011 | NZ      |     4 |
| 1011 | NZ      |     5 |
|      |         |       |
| 1012 | NZ      |     5 |
| 1012 | AUS     |     6 |
| 1012 | NZ      |     6 |
|      |         |       |
| 1013 | AUS     |     5 |
| 1013 | AUS     |     5 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

Output required:

```
+------+---------+-------+
|  id  | country | score |
+------+---------+-------+
| 1011 | JPN     | 5     |
| 1011 | JPN     | 5     |
| 1011 | NZ      | 4     |
| 1011 | NZ      | 5     |
|      |         |       |
| id   | country | score |
| 1012 | NZ      | 5     |
| 1012 | AUS     | 6     |
| 1012 | NZ      | 6     |
|      |         |       |
| id   | country | score |
| 1013 | AUS     | 5     |
| 1013 | AUS     | 5     |
+------+---------+-------+
```

Original DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'id':[1011,1011,1011,1011,1012,1012,1012,1013,1013],
'country':[JPN,JPN,NZ,NZ,NZ,AUS,NZ,AUS,AUS]
,'score':[5,5,4,5,5,6,6,5,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

DF with blank row inserted:

```
df1= df.groupby('id').apply(lambda d: d.append({'id': d.name}, ignore_index=True).astype({'id': int})).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Many thanks
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, with added custom `DataFrame`, last remove last 2 rows by `iloc`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns), df.columns], columns=df.columns)
df1= (df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda d: d.append(df2))
        .iloc[:-2]
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
      id  country  score
0   1011      JPN      5
1   1011      JPN      5
2   1011       NZ      4
3   1011       NZ      5
4                       
5     id  country  score
6   1012       NZ      5
7   1012      AUS      6
8   1012       NZ      6
9                       
10    id  country  score
11  1013      AUS      5
12  1013      AUS      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient tho:

```
print(df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.append(dict.fromkeys(data.keys(), ''), ignore_index=True).append({k:k for k in data.keys()}, ignore_index=True)).reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1])
```

Output:

```
    country    id  score
0       JPN  1011      5
1       JPN  1011      5
2        NZ  1011      4
3        NZ  1011      5
4                       
5   country    id  score
6        NZ  1012      5
7       AUS  1012      6
8        NZ  1012      6
9                       
10  country    id  score
11      AUS  1013      5
12      AUS  1013      5
13
```